# Phase stable cable vendors

Tags: rf, cable-assemblies

I'm looking for reputable vendors to purchase phase stable cables for VNA measurements of body area networks. I found Huber + Suhner and Pasternack Enterprizes, but can't find anyone else reputable. Do you know of other reputable vendors that sell high quality RF products? Thanks in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm. First time that I've heard someone call Pasternack "reputable."

Depending on your requirements, you might find cable from Times Microwave or Andrew to be acceptable; these are often good brands for precision, phase stable applications.

Answer (score 2):

Pasternack is OK, but reasonably low end. I'd use them for generic cables, but not for phase stable stuff. Gore sells/sold some good stuff. Take a look at these web sites

www.mwjournal.com Microwave Journal
www.wmrf.com Microwaves and RF magazine
www.rfcafe.com Good RF site.

Dave

Answer (score 1):

Mini-Circuits carries a surprisingly economical line of cables and adapters with very good quality.